# Как лучше сделать программу для тестирования с сохранением результатов?

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно написать программу для тестирования с подсчетом времени на выполнение каждого задания и теста в целом, и подсчетом баллов. И дальше все  ответы должны где-то сохраняться, чтобы потом можно было просмотреть все данные участника тестирования(время, баллы). Каким образом это можно сделать?